# Why does memory usage increase with each click to the button in Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

Even though there is no event related to the button, every time i clicked the button the memory usage increases slowly. What causes this? Thank you.

Comment: This does not happen in general with WinForms.  Post some simple code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I only created a new Windows Forms Project and added a Button from toolbox. No code. After that I tracked the memory usage from task manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET used a managed memory model, that means that there is a garbage collector that is responsible for freeing memory for objects that are no longer needed.  Rather than spending the time and effort of freeing memory for each object as soon as possible, the garbage collection waits until the system needs memory or enough time has passed that it decides to perform a collection.  When that collection is performed it will go around and look for objects that don't need to be in memory any more and deallocate them.  (In reality it actually finds everything that is needed, and saves all of those, leaving everything that wasn't saved to go away, but you don't need to think of it that way.)

In most all instances the GC does a great job of managing memory.  You simply shouldn't think about it most of the time.

Comment: So, no need to worry about it. Thanks.